# Моя форма не работает

Tags: python, django

У меня есть страница с формой, при заполнении которой пользователь переходит на страницу оплаты, после нажатия кнопки ничего не происходит и никаких ошибок я не получаю:

about.html

```
{% extends "base.html" %}
{% block title %}
<title>
  {{ cheat.title }}
</title>
{% endblock %}
{% block content %}
  <div class="detail">
    <h1>{{ cheat.title }}</h1>
    <p>{{ cheat.price }}</p>
    <form class="payment" action=".">
      {{ form.as_p }}
      {% csrf_token %}
      <input type="submit" value="buy">
    </form>
  </div>
{% endblock %}
```

views.py

```
def about(request, price, slug):
    cheat = get_object_or_404(Subscription, price=price, slug=slug)
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = SubscribeForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            cost = cheat.price * form.month
            return render(request, 'subs/payment.html', {'cost': cost})
    else:
        form = SubscribeForm()
        return render(request, 'subs/about.html', {'form': form, 'cheat': cheat})
```

В чём моя проблема?

Comment: Ваша форма отправляет GET-запрос, условие `if request.method == 'POST'` не выполняется, поэтому ничего и не происходит

Comment: @andreymal да, так форма и работает, разве нет? отображение должно отрендерить форму по умолчанию, когда она вызывается в первый раз и, затем, перерендерить её, в том случае, если возникли какие-либо ошибки при работе с её полями. В случае же успеха, после обработки "правильных" данных отображение перенаправляет пользователя на новую (другую) страницу. Для того чтобы выполнить все эти действия, отображение должно знать вызвано ли оно в первый раз для отрисовки формы по умолчанию, а если это не так, то провести валидацию полученных данных.

Comment: Если вас устраивает, как работает форма, и вы хотите просто обработать GET-запрос, значит вам нужно удалить условие `if request.method == 'POST'`

Comment: @andreymal Мне нужно, чтобы форма в первый раз отправляла GET запрос, получала данные, а потом обработчик принял от неё POST запрос. пушто так формы и работают

Comment: То есть кнопку в форме требуется нажимать два раза для двух запросов? Об этом ничего не сказано в вопросе и не написано в коде. Уточните текст вопроса

Comment: я думаю andreymal говорит, что нужно добавить     `<form class="payment" action="." method="post">` в Вашей форме на странице.

Comment: @AndreyMaslov помогло, спасибо